# Android app throws OutOfMemoryError some times

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm trying to add a JSONArray to a JSONObject. Most of the time this works fine, but some times an OutOfMemoryError is thrown.

Code:

```
...
...
JSONObject oneField = new JSONObject();
oneField.put("qId", formQid);
oneField.put("value", finalEnumValuesJsonArray.toString()); 
//exception thrown at above line(FormUtils.java:1947)
...
...
```

Stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-27190
Process: com.myapp.qa, PID: 7906
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:317)
at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:252)
at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:672)
at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:602)
at org.json.JSONArray.toString(JSONArray.java:574)
at com.myapp.utils.FormUtils.getFormResponseInNewFormat(FormUtils.java:1947)
```

What can be done to prevent this error?

Comment: What is the content of `finalEnumValuesJsonArray`?

Comment: if you have such huge output `json` use `JsonWriter` then

Comment: Is this code part of a loop?

Comment: @Pravin Sonawane- `finalEnumValuesJsonArray` contains `JSONObject`s with two elements each.

Comment: @pskink- thanks, i'll follow up on JsonWriter and how it can replace my existing code!

Comment: @Christine- Yes, its a loop where multiple `JSONObject`s are added to `finalEnumValuesJsonArray`

Comment: @PrasadPawar Ok. Doesn't seem like a huge JsonObject. Any other parts of the code you suspect we can look at?

Comment: @PravinSonawane i'd be happy to share more code but the issue is only with JSONArray.toString() method throwing OutOfMemory error. I'm just exploring alternatives that can be used to avoid this.